# Incorrect value from textbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying a simple thing i.e fetch data from textbox but it does not give me correct value?

```
function cal() {

    var a;
    var b;
    var c;


    //    document.getElementById("cals").innerHTML=btn;
    a = document.getElementById("txta").value;
    b = document.getElementById("txtb").value;
    c = document.getElementById("txtc").value;


    if (a.valueOf() > b.valueOf()) {
        if (a.valueOf() > c.valueOf()) {
            document.write("A is grater");
        } else {
            document.write("c is grater");
        }
    } else {
        if (b.valueOf() > c.valueOf()) {
            document.write("B is grater");
        } else {
            document.write("c is grater");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where you didn't get correct value? Did you got a,b,c value?

Comment: is it a numbers? or what are a/b/c?

Comment: its working absolutely here http://jsfiddle.net/qq2P5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead if is int number using parseInt:

```
            if (parseInt(a, 10)>parseInt(b, 10))
            {    
                if (parseInt(a, 10)>parseInt(c, 10))
                {
                    document.write("A is grater");
                }
                else
                {
                    document.write("c is grater");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(parseInt(b, 10)>parseInt(c, 10))
                {
                    document.write("B is grater");
                }else
                {
                    document.write("c is grater");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Don't use `parseInt` without a radix.

Comment: yes I have corrected, using radix is mandatory for parseInt to get correct value and don't have strange problem, thanks @Quentin

Comment: Why not parse the textbox value when declaring "b" (b = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtb").value, 10)) instead of parsing "b" to int multiple times? The same goes for "a" and "c" ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

```
function cal() {
    var a,b,c, text;

    a = parseInt(document.getElementById("txta").value,10);
    b = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtb").value,10);
    c = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtc").value,10);

    if (a > b && a > c) text = "A is grater"
    else if (b > c) text = "B is grater"
    else  text = "C is grater"

    document.write(text);
}
```